# Summarize values between two rows, according to criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, row, mutate

I have this dataframe

[my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71T5w.png)

where values in the 'Age' columns need to be summarize per the whole size range
i.e. now the data frame is like this:

```
     Size   Age 1   Age 2  Age 3
[1]    8      2       8      5
[2]   8.5     4       7      9
[3]    9      1       11     45
[4]   9.5     3        2      0
```

But i want this

```
       Size   Age 1   Age 2  Age 3
[1+2]   8      6       15     16  
[3+4]   9      4       13     45
```

Which function is better to use in R?

I thought but I don't tried, to use rowwise () together with mutate (), but I don't know how to set the criteria.

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Valentina Caserta! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite easily with the `dplyr` library. (You may need to `install.packages("dplyr")` if you haven't already.)

Using dplyr functions, we can group by a new grouping column, `size`, replacing the existing `size` column with values that have been rounded down to the nearest whole number. Then we just `summarise` `across` all the columns that `starts_with` `"Age"` and `sum` up the values.

```r
require(dplyr)

my_df |>
  group_by(size = floor(size)) |>
  summarise(
    across(starts_with("Age"), sum)
  )
```